# Different poster image at the end of the video (media js)

Tags: jquery, mediaelement.js

I'm using the following:

```
   jQuery("video").mediaelementplayer({
        features: ["playpause","progress","current","duration","volume","fullscreen"],
        success:  function (mediaElement, domObject) { 
            mediaElement.addEventListener("ended", function(e){ 
                // Revert to the poster image when ended
                var $thisMediaElement = (mediaElement.id) ? jQuery("#"+mediaElement.id) : jQuery(mediaElement);
                $thisMediaElement.parents(".mejs-inner").find(".mejs-poster").show();
            });
        }
    });
```

to revert back to a poster image at the end of a video being played. How would I get it to revert to a new image, i.e `poster-start.png` (video starts), then (video ends) `poster-end.png`?

Answer (score 1):

The way I do this is by changing the html in the `mejs-poster` div in the end function. Add this line in the end function just below where you set the `$thisMediaElement` variable.

```
$thisMediaElement
    .parents(".mejs-inner")
    .find(".mejs-poster")
    .html('<img src="images/poster2.png">');
```